# How can I bind props in scss tag when importing a mixin?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3, scss-mixins

In my project, vue version is
vue@3.2.40, style tag lang is `scss`.

I have a div that I want to style

```
<div ref="targetRef" v-show="isVisible" class="tooltip">

   <slot></slot>

</div>
```

In script, I get the alignment type from props:

```
const props = defineProps({
  text: String,
  alignment: {
    type: String as PropType<Alignment>,
    default: 'top',
  },
}
```

I want to import a mixin in the style tag where I pass my alignment as a variable. So whatever the alignment is, I want to import that mixin style. Here is what I tried;

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>    
    .tooltip {
      $alignment: v-bind(alignment);
      @include triangleWithAlignment($alignment);  
      }
</style>
```

It doesn't work and I don't know how to debug it. I tried @debug $alignment but didn't console anything.

If I give a dynamic class to the div with `:class="`-${alignment}`"`, and import the mixin for each class like:

```
  &.-top {
    @include triangleWithAlignment(top);
  }
```

It works, But it is repetitive for each class, is there a better way to do it?